# Textedit + CombBox + pyqt4

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, pyqt4, textedit

I need help with a program. I need use a texedit + combobox.
I need open a txt and set it to my textedit ( i've alredy did it)
than i need use my cursor, to get some word, than use a specific thing in my combobox... for example Polarity, this box have only numbers, 1,-1,0
and with a button, i need save it on a new txt or other archive.
I have a menu bar with open,new,save and close. I can open a file modify it and save, but i want to save with a buttom, the word that i  underline(with cursor) + the number i selected and saved for that word.... it's possible? how i can do it?
It's better using table widget? im new using pyqt4 :(
please help me... i dont know how to do this thing ..

Comment: we can help you if you post code

Comment: could you please create a simple version of your code and add it the post? that's way we can understand you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get started with PyQt4 is to look at some working examples that are similar to the application you want to write. The PyQt4 source has lots of these - download it from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), and have a look in the *examples* directory.

In addition to this, there are numerous tutorials available that will help get you started. A good place to start looking is the [PyQt4 wiki](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials).

Once you've worked through a few tutorials, you will probably be able to achieve what you want quite easily. And if you get stuck on something, you can always come back and ask about it on SO (just make sure to ask a *specific* question, and post the code that you have so far).

Comment: my hole code is to big to put it here...
well, i dont understand how to do it..
- I have a textEdit, and a Combobox(with -1,1,0). I have a menu, with Open and save file. I open a txt. than i need underline ONE word, select or -1,1 or 0... and click on a button to save it. when i click on this button, i need save that number for that word. i dont know how many words i will need do that. i need know how to underline a word, and save it with the specific number of the combobox. Anyone knows how to do that?  if you want a "part" of my code say what part you need.. the save..open.. please help me!

Comment: @MarcoBochernitsan. Sorry - I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: hmm..i will try again...
I have a main window, with open and save. i can open a txt file. i need open it into a textEdit. Than, i have a ComboBox with three things

Comment: hmm..i will try again...
I have a main window, with open and save. i can open a txt file. i need open it into a textEdit. Than, i have a ComboBox with three numbers(1,-1 and 0). i Need underline a word, in the text that i opened and select a number(1,-1,0) for this word. than i need save it into a new txt, with the old txt + the word that i underlined something like this:
(txt blablablalbla.
 Word(underlined),-1;Word(underlined),0;)
thanks for trying to helping me ;)

Comment: @MarcoBochernitsan. Please add further information by editing your question, rather than adding comments.